How Do You Select Features for Machine Learning Models with Hundreds of Variables in Kaggle Competitions?
I'm currently participating in a Kaggle competition, and my dataset contains around 100 variables. I'm wondering how others usually approach feature selection when they have so many variables, especially if they don’t have expert knowledge of the domain.
A few specific questions I have:

What techniques or methods do you use to efficiently select features in competitions with large datasets?
Do you rely on automated feature selection methods like PCA, Random Forest feature importance, or Lasso, or do you have other go-to strategies?
How do you handle overfitting when you have a lot of variables but limited knowledge of which ones are actually important?
Do you typically perform Exploratory Data Analysis (EDA) when dealing with hundreds of variables, and if so, how do you approach it with such a large feature set?
Have you found certain strategies to be more effective in competitions, particularly with high-dimensional data?

I would love to hear about your experiences or tips that have worked for you in past competitions. Thanks for any insights!
